# Opportunity created date?

Tags: apex, fields

Is it possible to get the Opportunity `created date` from Salesforce? I don't see any standard fields that hold the data information but when looking at `Created By` field you can see a date next to the user ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This field is standard and exists on every opportunity. Here it is:

[image].

You are correct, however, that it doesn't appear in the standard field list on the object. If you would like to see it, you can make a calc field that references it, like so:
[image]

Comment: Can I use CreatedDate directly or do I need to create a calc field to reference in my apex/VF?

Comment: You can use CreatedDate directly in Apex/VF, for sure. You can't edit, however.

Answer (score 0):

One can view the standard and custom fields better, using the developer console and then click on "File--->Open", filter out any sObject to view its standard and custom fields.

**P.S.:- CreatedDate field is available on opportunity, its just not visible on standard salesforce opportunity page.

Also, one can edit the createdDate field through enabling "Create Audit Fields" which could be enabled by generating a support ticket with salesforce support.**